# Why does the ortho effect not work here?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

The basicity order of aniline and 2,6-tertiary butyl aniline is the latter greater than the former. Why does the ortho effect not make it the other way around? Or am I missing something?[image]

Comment: Is your first sentence a statement or a question? Providing pKb's would be helpful.

Comment: First thing to correct is that ortho effect is  applicable only when u have -COOH..ie..comparing acidity or stuff for substituted benzoic acid.

Comment: Here u have to consider SIP effect ....

Comment: I don't know where to find pKbs, sorry :(

Comment: Ortho effect is present in anilines too

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15412/why-can-the-lone-pair-not-align-with-the-phenyl-moiety-in-2-6-xylidine https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7683/ortho-effect-in-substituted-aromatic-acids-and-bases

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14767/steric-hindrance-and-br%c3%b8nsted-basicity https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/87461/is-steric-inhibition-of-resonance-or-steric-inhibition-of-protonation-dominant-i

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand all of the answers very much, but I think I caught the gist of it. Does it mean that m-xylene with NH2 meta to both is less basic that with the NH2 between the CH3's? Even with the double ortho effect?